# Disable port 1099 on Mule 3.8

Tags: mule, jmx

Forgive me if this question has been asked before, but searching for this issue hasn't turned up anything I can use.  Most of the discussions are about enabling the port while I want to be able to disable it.

I have several legacy servers that are running Linux RHE 7 with Apache Mule 3.8 installed.  Security insists that port 1099 be closed, which I gather is used by JMX.  3.8 is actually out of support now, but we still have it running on a number servers and they are reluctant to upgrade since they would have to make many changes to their own software.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

PS. I don't actually work with Mule normally so my knowledge of it is limited to what I have picked up from having to upgrade the servers from time to time.

What I have found from searching around is that you can disable this in 3.9, with the following.

wrapper.java.additional.15=Xnoagent
wrapper.java.additional.16=-Dmule.agent.enabled=false

And this works fine on Mule 3.9 instances we have installed.  However this doesn't work on Mule 3.8.  I have tried a few other variations on this but nothing has worked yet.

Answer (score 0):

That's not accurate. Mule doesn't activate port 1099 nor JMX by default. The configuration you mentioned works for all Mule 3.x releases. However it is for the Mule Management Console agent. Unless it's port has been set to something different in the file wrapper.conf the default port it uses is 7777. If it was changed to something else it should be in the wrapper.conf file.

If the port 1099 is actually used for JMX it has been configured in wrapper.conf using Java arguments. Review that file to find if there are any such Java parameters in there.

Another alternative is that some application is actually opening that port for something, like listening to inbound HTTP request. You would need to review each Mule application deployed in that Mule 3.8 server to understand that.